# Games that illustrate attacking themes

Tags: attack, teaching

I have recently made an agreement with a bunch of highly interested but still inexperienced players and I will become their trainer. My plan is to have 1-2 meetings per week with them to talk about some relevant strategical topics and prepare their "training plan" for the days we will not meet (by now, consisting mostly of tactics and analysis of their own games)

I could find some illustrative games for most of the strategical themes that I would like to have a look at with them, like open files, the 7th rank, minor piece comparison (good and bad bishop, active and passive knights...), as well as pawn structure. I've also chosen a list of must-know theoretical endgames for them to learn.

However, before starting with these "more subtle" strategical topics, I would to begin with a few lessons on material and attack. Material advantage and simplification are no problem, but I am struggling to find illustrative games showing different types of attack. Ideally, the games should be easy to understand from a tactical perspective (by that I mean that, despite of course there being tactical complications, the strategical ideas should still be clear behind the forced-move mess) Classical games are also preferred since modern ones often require a great understanding of a particular type of position to follow, and I would prefer to show a more global view of attacking in chess.

Could you please provide me some reference to attacking games you consider illustrative/enjoyable? Any help is appreciated, even it you only contribute with one game.  I would like to cover the following topics:

- Attacking a king in the center. First game in Nimzowitsch's book is great here. Morphy also comes to the rescue. What other examples do you know?
- Converting development advantage into attack against the king.
- Piece power in opened-center positions.
- Maneuvering the pieces into the enemy's castled position (more closed-position focused)
- Bayonet attacks (opposite-side castling): Here I am pretty much served, as some opening books on the Sicilian and French made the job for me, but other examples are welcome.
- Bayonet-attacks (kings castled on the same side): The best examples I found come from the King's Indian Defence. What else can I look for?

(After finding a good collection of games, I intend to show them 1-2 games per theme, and give them the rest so that they can make the analysis themselves)

Comment: If you want modern out and out attacking games Marc Esserman is not a bad player to look at. His most famous victory: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1630005

Comment: Thank you! This particular game is great for showing attack against a king in the center. I will look for more of this guy!

Comment: A collection search on chessgames.com using your key word should provide you with plenty of examples.  Your search could also be of famous example books:  AOAC, 100 Awesome Chess..., The Most Instructive..., etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes to maneuvering pieces to an enemy's king in a position, the following famous game with a king walk comes to my mind. The position isn't quite closed, but it does illustrate an attacking theme of walking the king across the board to a castled king. It has been nicknamed "A Long Walk Off a Short Peer" by [chessgames.com.](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1124533&kpage=5)

```
[Title "Nigel Short-Jan Timman, Interpolis 15th, Tiligribg Netherlands, 1991"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 Nf6 2. e5 Nd5 3. d4 d6 4. Nf3 g6 5. Bc4 Nb6 6. Bb3 Bg7 7. Qe2 Nc6 8. O-O O-O 9. h3 a5 10. a4 dxe5 11. dxe5 Nd4 12. Nxd4 Qxd4 13. Re1 e6 14. Nd2 Nd5 15. Nf3 Qc5 16. Qe4 Qb4 17. Bc4 Nb6 18. b3 Nxc4 19. bxc4 Re8 20. Rd1 Qc5 21. Qh4 b6 22. Be3 Qc6 23. Bh6 Bh8 24. Rd8 Bb7 25. Rad1 Bg7 26. R8d7 Rf8 27. Bxg7 Kxg7 28. R1d4 Rae8 29. Qf6+ Kg8 30. h4 h5 31. Kh2 Rc8 32. Kg3 Rce8 33. Kf4 Bc8 34. Kg5
```

Comment: For anyone interested in an annotated version, this game is the topic of the chapter about controlling the open file in John Nunn's _Understanding Chess Move by Move_.